# How to update data in same table with same column but for different version in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have one table with some column in SQL just like below:

| id | parameter_id | source_of_configuration | is_deleted | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Standard | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | tblParamVal | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | TuningSheet | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | Standard | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | tblPTO | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | Standard | 0 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | Standard | 0 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 | Standard | 0 | 2 |
| 9 | 4 | Standard | 0 | 2 |

I want to update `source_of_configuration` column data for `version` 2 and need to set it from `version` 1 based on `parameter_id` column. How can I do that with sql query?

Expected result is :

| id | parameter_id | source_of_configuration | is_deleted | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Standard | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | tblParamVal | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | TuningSheet | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | Standard | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | tblPTO | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | Standard | 0 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 | tblParamVal | 0 | 2 |
| 8 | 3 | TuningSheet | 0 | 2 |
| 9 | 4 | Standard | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an `UPDATE JOIN` statement as the following:

```
update t 
set t.source_of_configuration = d.source_of_configuration
from
tbl t join tbl d
on t.parameter_id = d.parameter_id
where d.version = 1 and t.version = 2 and 
      t.source_of_configuration <> d.source_of_configuration
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DInuWl9U)